# JQuery to set Image SRC as body background-image

Tags: jquery, background-image

I have set of images within UL like this :

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img scr="image1.png">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img scr="image2.png">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img scr="image3.png">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Upon click on each image, I want that Image's src to be applied to body as "background-image".

I'm not JQuery expert, So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('#id-of-ul a').click(function(){
var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
$('body').css('backgroundImage','url('+src+')');

})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$document.ready(function () {
    $("img").click(function () {
        $(body).css("background-image", $(this).attr("src"));
    });
});
```

Comment: then he won't need the `<a href=''>` tags

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
  $(a).click(function() {
    $(body).css('background-image',this.find(img).attr('src'))
  });
});
</script>
```